# How to change transaction logs size in singlestore

Tags: transaction-log, singlestore

We have a table that memsql studio says is in 5gb in size, though on disk we see approx 27gb in the data folder. After further analyzing it seems the data/logs is holding approx 16gb.
Is this needed ? is there a way to clean it ?

Answer (score 1):

It applies to version 7.0 and higher and for reference databases, singlestore create smaller log files by default (64 mb). Both of those are controllable by global variables log_file_size_partitions and log_file_size_ref_dbs.

Note: the default unit is in bytes so first convert any larger unit to bytes then set it to the variables.

**For Example:**

```
show variables like '%log_file_size_partitions';
show variables like '%log_file_size_ref_dbs';

set @log_file_size_ref_dbs = 102444;
set @log_file_size_partitions = =102444;
```

so when you set it up to the desired value it won't store more logs than the size of variables.

Comment: Is this immediate ?
Changed the log_file_size but nothing happened.